# Can I add Microdata properties in deeply nested HTML?

Tags: html5, microdata

Can I define a `<span itemprop="example">` within an undefined parent `div` if that parent `div`’s parent `div` is defined?

Here is the example:

```html
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <p>some text and lorem ipsum</p>
    <div class="random">
       <span itemprop="price">$40</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation I can't work this out. However in the example for itemprop - http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#microdata_itemprop they use a span where you have <div class="random">. Could you use a span? You could always give it a go and test with http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Comment: so you are aware, I don't think the rich snippets testing tool works with schema.org standard at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `itemprop` attribute within an HTML tag even if the immediate enclosing HTML tag brackets, such as `<div>` and `</div>`, does not have `itemscope` and `itemtype`, as long as some level of enclosing tag brackets does define the item scope and type.

The Microdata attributes can be used in any type of HTML tags, not just `<div>` and `<span>`, and many intervening HTML tags and nesting levels may occur.

The `itemprop` is deemed to apply to the nearest enclosing `itemscope`.